# Returning an NA for sd

Tags: r, variance

I am trying to get get the variance of variable (GD1) in my dataset (CETeen), but the output keeps returning an "NA" when I use the basic variance function. I know there are some NA's in the data, but I am not sure if this is the culprit. I am new to R and still learning, is there a better way to get the variance for this variable, or a way to figure out the issue?

var(CETeen$GD1)

[1] NA

Comment: Readind the help page (`?var`) will give you the answer to your question. And `sd` stands for standard deviation.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compute the variance of a set containing `NA`:

```
R> var(c(1,2,3,NA,5))
[1] NA
R> var(c(1,2,3,NA,5), na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 2.91667
R>
```

So either treat / filter your data, or tell `var()` to skip the `NA` values.